# Add date using echo without calculating

Tags: vmware-esxi, cron, date, echo

I should add the line to /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root on my ESXi: `/bin/echo` `"0 3 * * 6 /ghettoVCB-master/ghettoVCB.sh -g /ghettoVCB-master/text.conf -f /ghettoVCB-master/text.list > /var/log/ghettoVCB-month-$(date +%m)-week-$((($(date +\%d)-1)/7+1)).log"` `>>` `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`.

But this comandline adds a reasult of `$(date +%m)` and `$((($(date +\%d)-1)/7+1))`.

How to add this line as a formula? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to improve here:

- `cron` will not notice changes made directly to the files in `/var/spool/cron`. Use `crontab -e` instead.
  There's also `/etc/crontab`, which might be preferred for system-wide maintenance tasks like this.
  (The crontabs in `/etc` (also `/etc/cron.*`) are the only ones you can edit directly. They also have a different format than the ones exposed via the `crontab` command.)
- `%` is a special character in crontabs. Escape it with a backslash when using it in arguments, e.g. `date +\%m`.
- `date` should understand the format string `%W` as "week number of year, with Monday as first day of week (00..53)" -- no need to calculate it yourself.
- Your cron might not run the crontab commands in a shell that supports process substitution (`$()`). You can explicitly run your command in a shell like `sh -c 'echo $(date) > /tmp/foo'` to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for your cron-related advices. As I got, `start.sh` with all expressions is my way. As I found, all my settings will be removed at ESXi system restart If I put start.sh directly to cron file. Adding the command that changes the cron file at `/etc/rc.local.d/local.sh` should help.